# TinyMCE4- How to allow certain styles while pasting itself on Text Editor?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

While pasting data from web/word to TinyMCE4 editor, only  certain styles should be allowed & rest other styles should be removed.

Only Following styles should be allowed:
Bold/Italic/Bullet/Numbered List/Hyperlink/StrikeThrough/Underline

> Here is the [Fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/nngaab) which I have tried. It is not working for Underline & StrikeThrough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following control characters inside your current `valid_elements` options list for pasting from web or editors

```
s/span,span[style=text-decoration: line-through;]
```

please note that you should use the `paste_word_valid_elements:` too for allowing valid elements while pasting from word.
See [**`FIDDLE`**](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/nngaab/1)

Comment: One query- why it converting span style decoration with u & s tag respectively? Can't we retain ?

Comment: The `s/span` is for superscript `u/span` for underline and `span[style=text-decoration: line-through;]` for strikethrough, or did i not get what you are asking ?

Comment: Earlier it was coming like <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">  for strike through but now it is coming like <u> . This thing I am checking while saving the data in backend from this editor

Comment: are you saying that for strike through it is coming with a `<u>` tag instead of `<span>`? @PranavKumar can you add a sample html so i can test  ?

Comment: Yes ! I tested ! Earlier it was coming with span but now  it is coming with tag u

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166801/discussion-between-pranav-kumar-and-muhammad-omer-aslam).

Comment: How come it changed to `<u>` tag i tried various combinations but could not end up having `<u>` tag for `strike-through` ? how are you getting it can you add the configurations that generate this behavior on the fiddle so i can inspect otherwise we can add `u[style=text-decoration: line-through;]` for currently getting it fixed @PranavKumar

Comment: Sorry buddy! wrongly I wrote. Here is the concern :  For strike through:
<span style="style=text-decoration: line-through;"></span>, is expected. But now I am getting as <s></s> & same for underline <u></u>. Why this u & s tag is coming?? Can't it come like  
<span style="style=text-decoration: line-through;"></span> ???? Sorry for my previous wrong response. anyway, Really thanks & lots of love for your help till now :)

Comment: u & s tags are depreciated by Editor. Then why I am getting this for underline & strike-through. This is creating some issue. Can u help me out ?

Comment: Hmm give me some time i will figure it out once i reach home.